# Python code boilerplate generation/editing like in Sublime for VS Code

Tags: visual-studio-code, autocomplete, sublimetext, code-snippets, vscode-snippets

In a Sublime `.py` file when you type the letter c you get a suggestion for a new class. Press `Tab` and you get

[image]

with the multicursor adequately set. How do you do this in VS Code? The py plugin with IntelliSense only fills per keyword, Intellicode and TabNine are overkill.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can download snippet extensions (like [this one](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=cstrap.python-snippets), that contains the snippet you're interested in)

Otherwise, you can also define your own snippets, as specified in [the VS Code documentation](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/userdefinedsnippets#_create-your-own-snippets)

Comment: i had tried other snippet extensions and they were not good so had given up on them. this one nails it though. i thank you